# Kotlin coroutines onErrorReturn (RX Java counterpart)

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, rx-java2

In RX Java there is a possibility to provide a default value in case of error, with a variety of `onError...` methods.

What is the counterpart in Kotlin coroutines?

I understand I can wrap code inside `launch` or `await` calls in `try...catch`, but maybe there is a better solution?

What I need to convert this RX code to coroutines:

```
Single.zip(
    call1().onErrorResumeNext().observeOn(Dispatchers.IO),
    call2().onErrorReturnItem(DummyObject()).observeOn(Dispatchers.IO),
    call3().observeOn(Dispatchers.IO),
    result1, result2, result3 -> [zipper func]
)
```

And I don't see an attractive solution for that.

Comment: It's difficult to know what an "attractive" solution would be. Coroutines are designed especially to mimic imperative code, because there's an opinion that functional constructs like the one used by RxJava are "unattractive". What I could do is provide an example as close as possible to the expected behaviour, based on `async`, `awaitAll`, and `runCatching` but would it be attractive  to you ? I can't say

Comment: This being said, if you prefer functional operators, it is possible to forge your own using extension functions. There may be libraries providing that kind of convenience already. That's the strength of coroutines: providing building blocks to allow each and everyone to create its own high-level concurrency tools above it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all in `catch{}` [operator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/catch.html):

- Rethrow using `throw`
- `emit` new value
- Ignore/log

> Conceptually, the action of catch operator is similar to wrapping the code of upstream flows with try { ... } catch (e: Throwable) { action(e) }

Comment: Yeah, that should work, but why should we use flow? I believe that Single should be converted into plain coroutines.

Comment: You asked for counterparts of Rx streams! error handling, which is Flow error handling in Kotlin Coroutines. If you want to return single value, why not refactor each call1/call2/call3 to return single value as well as suspending function?

Comment: As for me, Rx streams (like Observable) counterpart is Flow, you are right. But I used to treat Single as a one-shot operation, which is translated to the coroutines itself, not Flow.

Comment: The idea behind combining call1/2/3 is to run them in parallel.

Comment: You can run susending coroutines in parallel by wrapping them in `async`